# Automatically update a C# Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce, installshield-le, automatic-updates

I want my application to automatically check for updates and update the application if needed. I installed InstallShield Limited edition, but when I went to the update section I found out that I need to install FlexNet which requires me to purchase it.

I found out that Windows has stopped supporting Windows Installer which is why in Visual Studio 2013 it's not listed in the setup and deployment section.

I also read about ClickOnce, but there is a small issue when I tried to deploy my application to the FTP server. It asked for the username and password, but it added a warning that these values will be in plain text! So, what should I do? Is there another third-party way of creating an installer and setting up automatic updates?

Comment: In the research I've done, I've seen some open source solutions. However, I went with using WyBuild - note that while it is still being sold, it hasn't been updated in several years.

Comment: I've never encountered this using ClickOnce.  Are you sure the prompt isn't just coming from the FTP server? Have you tried serving the published folder from a different location?

Comment: @JerryFederspiel Probably it is the ftp server because I was publishing it directly to the server. Can I deploy it simply in my pc and upload the newly created folder on the server? but with clickonce everytime I will upload a 76MB folder can I just upload the newest and delete the previous ones will this cause any problems?

Comment: You can delete the old one with ClickOnce

Comment: Yes, it was because you were publishing directly over FTP.  Yes you can upload the new stuff on the server and delete the previous version.  You can bring back the old Setup/Deployment projects with this extension released by MS: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx but it isn't the best choice for auto-updated, ClickOnce is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used ClickOnce with dozens of applications and have never seen the username/password prompt. My process is:

1. Declare the application is downloaded from "http://www.yourSite.com/yourApp/"
2. Publish to folder "yourApp" in whatever location you want
3. Drag and drop that whole folder into your WWW space on your server
4. Email your users the link "http://www.yourSite.com/yourApp/yourApp.application"

For updates, just repeat this same process (except emailing users), and everything else takes care of itself. Be sure check the box in your application settings that tells it to check for updates of course.

Comment: In my experiences of using clickonce, I also usually distribute application from a webserver, and even run application from a link in a webpage. +1 for your good knowledge of clickonce :)

Comment: So you recommend ClickOnce? I have been trying to avoid it because I've read many articles where people say they regretted using it....

Comment: and what I did was I published it to ftp server probably that's why I was prompted with this issue, you know how when your brain stops working due to stress that's what was happening with me

Comment: Absolutely recommend ClickOnce! Publishing lower security apps that do not use File class or any potentially dangerous code is very simple. Publishing your app with a trusted certificate is trickier, but still possible with ClickOnce...but that's a whole other issue

Comment: thanks a lot, the application is for a small to medium center, it will be installed on 10-20 PC's so automatic update is very important for me instead of wasting my time updating each PC alone. I will give it a try and if it works I'll mark your answer as accepted :)

Comment: @scubasteve623 Can I set the update link as a google drive shareable link?

Comment: I don't believe Google Drive or Dropbox (know for sure) will work. I've only ever used SQL Server and WAMP to distribute with ClickOnce.

Comment: yes they didn't work, I had to use my own serve to share the my clickonce app, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

The prompt about the username and password only applies during the deployment. So I wouldn't deploy the app using FTP in a Starbucks using their Wi-Fi, but it should be fine at work or on your private network at home.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually answers any of the two questions (security concerns over using a plain FTP server).

Answer (score 2):

Consider looking:

- [How to: Manage Updates for a ClickOnce Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1zyc39fb.aspx)
- [How to: Check for Application Updates Programmatically Using the ClickOnce Deployment API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx)

You can distribute your application using a webserver, even your application can run from a link in a web page.

And also you can check for update using code.