# How to update WinForms application over the internet?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, hosting, desktop-application, auto-update

I am developing a winform application which is currently used by a small company consisting of 6 staff members.

Every single time I update my application, I need to travel 2 hours just to give them the updated application files. How can I let the application to check for update and update it over the internet automatically?

Please guide me to the right direction as in which hosting site should I upload my application to? Should I host it on my own Pc? Or do I even need hosting?

Comment: This is way to broad to answer here. You could look into a Web Service and make a call to see if there's a new version and if so download the new version or prompt them to go to a download page...

Comment: @Zaggler I see. So I should start looking into web service first for a start then

Comment: In my opinion yes as you would need a way to check if there's a new version or not...

Comment: @Zaggler Instead of reinventing the wheel again, is there any easier way to do it?

Comment: Well it sounds easier to do this unless you want to spam users in sending them an email for every version and or release to go download it... What would you think?

Comment: @Zaggler True. But then which web services do you recommend? There seems to be a lot.

Comment: @Student The most simple way would be using `ClickOnce`.

Comment: Eww ClickOnce lol, haven't heard that one for awhile... I was going to mention it but to save my breath and typing I didn't.

Comment: I think i tried clickonce before. But I am having problem using it on updating it through online

Comment: You may find this post helpful: [Automatically update winform application c#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32338837/3110834). I've used it both in local network and in internet.

Comment: @Zaggler Using ClickOnce, You can check for updates automatically and also by manually adding a check for update button. See the post for 2 useful links. Hope you find it helpful.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks! I was actually currently reading at the same site you provided. Guess I will give clickonce a go again then. Btw, if through online, can I just like upload my files to lets say dropbox?

Comment: I know what ClickOnce does I have used it but it has its fallbacks hense why I didn't recommend it...

Comment: @Zaggler While I've not encountered serious problems using ClickOnce, I believe it's really better than creating a custom update service. Creating a good and stable update service will be expensive comparing with ClickOnce. It's somehow reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @RezaAghaei me either my issues was because of service's and GAC issues. You cant perform these tasks with a ClickOnce deployment. There are others that go on but those were just a few of mine I had. ClickOnce would be better to go at then a web Service at least to see how it would work out for the OP...

Comment: @RezaAghaei Last question, if I don't have my own website, where can I upload my updated application to? This may seem like a general question but you may have more experience on this already, also costs is an issue for me.

Comment: Just use Drive and give the end users a link. Or search for free web hosting...

Comment: @Zaggler I thought clickonce was able to update the application automatically? So I would still need to give user a link to download it and then run clickonce again?

Comment: Yes but where are you going to put the files for the application? For it to update the application and files need to be hosted so ClickOnce can make a call to it. Otherwise it can't update...just look up ClickOnce and you find out everything needed to do this.

Comment: @Zaggler I saw a free webhosting site online. So basically my updated files can be hosted there, and in my application, the clickonce is set to check updates on launch right? If this is true, it seems so much easier

Comment: Correct you are on the right track!

Comment: Thanks so much for both of your help. Really appreciated it

Comment: If you want to use automatic updates in a standard and simple way you need a domain and a hosting space. For both of them there are free or commercial services. Choosing between them is up to you. Also if you want only distributing updates manually and notify the users to download and install updates, you can distribute your setup package even using Google Drive or Microsoft One Drive.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Noted! Im going for automatic updates!

Comment: @RezaAghaei Im sorry if I ask a lot of stupid questions but then is it ok for this Question to have no voted answers now?

Comment: No problem, it would be OK, also if someone have a good answer, they can post :)

Comment: By the way, perform enough tests on the solution before going to buy a service. You know the requirements better than any one else.

Comment: Have at it @Reza Aghaei, I felt it didn't need an answer because it was too broad here and that's why I was just commenting. Its up to you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically update winform application c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32338673/automatically-update-winform-application-c-sharp)

Comment: If you don't want to do the click once thing, set yourself up to be able to remotely connected into the other computers and then do the upgrade from your own office.  Might be handy for other needs too.  Everytime you save a trip, thank stakeoverflow!

Comment: You could save yourself the 2 hours trip by just using some large files transfer website like YouSendIt, or setting up a secured FTP server, and that's without changing anything in your software.